# How to set display precision for a pandas.Datafame containing a numpy.ndarray?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am storing `numpy.ndarray` of floats as elements of a `pandas.Datafame`.
I want to display such dataframe in a Jupyter Notebook with a custom precision.

Minimum working example (Python 3.9.12):

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(12345)

df = pd.DataFrame({
  'a': np.random.rand(1),
  'b': np.random.rand(1),
  'A': [np.random.rand(5)],
  'B': [np.random.rand(5)],
  'C': [np.random.rand(5)],
})
```

Using `display(df)`
prints too many decimal places and the entire arrays are not shown:

```
    a           b           A                                                   B                                                   C
0   0.929616    0.316376    [0.18391881167709445, 0.2045602785530397, 0.56...   [0.6531770968715709, 0.7489066375339118, 0.653...   [0.9613067360728214, 0.00838829794155349, 0.10..
```

With some arbitray precision, say 4 digits, I would like to display something like this:

```
    a       b       A                                           B                                   C
0   0.9296  0.3164  [0.1839, 0.2046, 0.5677, 0.5955, 0.9645]    [0.6532, 0.7489, 0.6536, 0.7477]    [0.9613, 0.008388 , 0.1064]
```

I have tried things like `with pd.option_context('display.precision', 4):` and `with np.printoptions(precision=4):` but neither of them seem to change anything for the array display.

How can I set the display precision to 4 places after the decimal point?

Comment: when you put an array in a dataframe cell, that column is `object` dtype.  Such a column could just as well contain strings that like the `str(anArray)`, or a list.  You've given up a lot control over cell display.  And don't dare to `tocsv` such a frame - unless you want headaches when reloading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I've learned from tracing the code involved: Pandas calls a function called [pprint_thing()](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/634b9402466c96c51e6667af935bde01e7ecf144/pandas/io/formats/printing.py#L164) in order to convert that numpy array into a string. It detects that the numpy array is iterable, and calls itself recursively. It calls `str()` on each individual element of the numpy array. Since it's calling `str()` on each individual float of the array, numpy's formatting options aren't respected. (I'm not sure why `pprint_thing()` does not respect Pandas' *own* formatting options - it seems like it would make sense for it to do that. But it seems that Pandas will only pay attention to those options if it is formatting a column of floats rather than a column of arrays.)

Therefore, I don't believe this is possible by using Pandas or numpy settings. A workaround is formatting the column yourself. As an example, the following code converts the array to string.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(12345)
np.set_printoptions(precision=4)

df = pd.DataFrame({
  'A': [np.random.rand(5)],
})
df['A'] = df['A'].apply(str)
print(df)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "formatting the column yourself"?

Comment: @GuiBeal Turning a numpy array into a string, as shown in the code example.